# Unable to bind SelectedItem of ListView when using ControlTemplate to define ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, listviewitem, selecteditem

I've defined a `ListViewItem` style as shown below

```
    <Style x:Key="BaseContentStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">            
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>            
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <ListViewItem Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"                                                                                                                 
                                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                  FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ebebeb"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ListViewPosition}" Value="Conference">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Conference}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#192942"/>                                
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ListViewPosition}" Value="Division">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Division}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1.5"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ListViewPosition}" Value="Team">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}"/>                                
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I've defined my `ListView` as follows

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AmericanAthleticTeams}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTeam, Mode=TwoWay}"                      
                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource BaseContentStyle}">
```

This is the `DataTemplate` used for the `ContentTemplate` in the `Style` template

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate" >
        <Grid >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="{Binding Logo, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" 
                   RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Height="15"
                   Width="15"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="5 0 0 0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid> 
    </DataTemplate>
```

And here is the ViewModel serving as the View's DataContext

```
class NCAAFBTeamsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public List<NCAAFBTeamViewModel> AmericanAthleticTeams { get; set; }
    private NCAAFBTeamViewModel team;

    public NCAAFBTeamsViewModel(List<NCAAFBTeamViewModel> americanAthleticTeams)
    {            
        AmericanAthleticTeams = americanAthleticTeams;
    }

    public NCAAFBTeamViewModel SelectedTeam
    {
        get { return team; }
        set
        {
            team = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm running into is the binding for the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListView` doesn't work as intended. In particular, when I click on one of the displayed `ListViewItem`s, the trigger isn't invoked for the bound SelectedTeam property in the ViewModel. I believe the issue resides with the `ControlTemplate` of my `Style` and that perhaps I'm not bubbling up high enough. I've scoured Google and unfortunately wasn't able to discover anything with regards to issues encountered with using a `ControlTemplate` to define `ListViewItem`s and the impact it has on the `SelectedItem` property. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Without the ItemContainerStyle, the ListView works as intended? It also looks odd that there is a ListViewItem in the ControlTemplate of a ListViewItem.

Comment: I really appreciate the reply. Actually when I replace the Template Setter of the Style with say a ContentTemplate Setter that has a Value of my DataTemplate along with Style.Triggers instead of ContentTemplate.Triggers the ListView is able to bind the SelectedItem property of the ListView. However, certain styling elements fail to work such as the Background property of my ListViewItems

Comment: Additionally, I've tried removing the ListViewItem from the ControlTemplate and though the SelectedItem now binds to the SelectedTeam property, the background property fails to work for the Setter properties of the ContentTemplate.Triggers.